# Animations and setVisibility

Tags: android, animation

I have a LinearLayout that I want to be able to show/hide by clicking on a "more details" link. I do this by calling

```
moreDetailsSection.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

or

```
moreDetailsSection.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

to show/hide it. This works fine, but I wanted to add an animation that makes the layout fields slide in nicely, but this is only run the first time the field is made visible, if I hide it and show it again the field simply appears all of a sudden. Here is the animation code (moreDetailsSection is the Layout in question):

```
      AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);

      Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
      animation.setDuration(250);
      set.addAnimation(animation);

      animation = new TranslateAnimation(
          Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
          Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f
      );
      animation.setDuration(150);
      set.addAnimation(animation);

      LayoutAnimationController controller =
          new LayoutAnimationController(set, 0.25f);
      moreDetailsSection.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
```

Any advice on how to make this run EACH time I show the layout and not only the first time?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I assume that the moreDetailsSection is INVISIBLE at first.
you just have to create the Animation object and call the following code when the more details link is clicked.

```
moreDetailsSection.startAnimation(animation);
moreDetailsSection.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: It turns out that the View won't be measured while it's visibility is `GONE`, so you would need to set the visibility to `VISIBLE` first when you use an animation that needs to know the View's bounds.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this line in your view for that layout:

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

Comment: For automatic and simple animations, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

**Use animation class**

```
fun setVisibilityWithAnimation(textView:TextView, visibility: Int) {

    if(visibility == View.VISIBLE){
        val animation = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0.0f, 1.0f)
        animation.duration = 1000
        animation.addUpdateListener {
            textView.alpha = it.animatedValue as Float
        }
        animation.addListener(
            onStart = {
                textView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        )
    }else if (visibility == View.GONE){
        val animation = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(1.0f, 0.0f)
        animation.duration = 1000
        animation.addUpdateListener {
            textView.alpha = it.animatedValue as Float
        }
        animation.addListener(
            onEnd = {
                textView.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        )
    }
}
```

use this way:

```
setVisibilityWithAnimation(labelTextView,View.GONE)
```